# How can be 'Class is implemented in both' issue be solved inside of an iOS framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am building an iOS framework which embeds a 3rd party static library. If the developer implementing the framework wants to also include the 3rd party static library which has been used, multiple 'Class is implemented in both' warnings will be displayed at runtime. How can I solve those warnings providing I can't rename the classes since the library is compiled?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't include the static lib when you compiling the developer implementing the framework.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are distributing manually, you have to tell everything(which 3rd party library to add in *Link Binary with Libraries*, *Other Linker Flags* & probably few more) to your client.
  Eg: [Install Manually](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) section for GoogleMaps
- If you have a Podspec(which probably means the 3rd party Library also does), then you can simply add *dependency* to it like [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)

BTW static library can't be embedded in an iOS Framework, you can only link it.